# Creating a cookie/session variable to A/B test forms on entire site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am testing two separate forms to see which generates the best leads and I'm having trouble getting to where I need to. So first we are using WordPress and the two forms are global (non landing page related).

With PHP I am generating a number of 0 or 1. If 0 form A loads, if 1 form B loads. So I got that working, then I looked into do a cookie to store that number so the form for the site visitor is the same if they browse across the site. Currently each page loads generates a new number so they'll see both forms if they click on contact and come back to it again later. Now with the cookie it's the same thing.

```
$aB = rand(0,1)
setcookie('user', $aB, time() + (86400*7));
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
   echo do_shortcode('[gravityform shortcode form B]');
} else { 
   echo do_shortcode('[gravityform shortcode form A]');
}
```

I'm looking into doing sessions but I'm still figuring out how I can keep if the site visitor gets a 0 how do I get that to follow them across the entire site as they browse until either they close or the cookie/session expires. After some testing with the cookies I realized this approach is probably not the best. I'm looking for suggestions in the best way to attach this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create custom setting field in website using below code in functions.php,

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_gcf_interface');
 function add_gcf_interface() {
    add_options_page('form option', 'form option', '8', 'functions', 'editglobalcustomfields');
}
function editglobalcustomfields() {
    ?>
    <div class='wrap'>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>

    <p><strong>Home page mode:</strong><br />
    <input type="number" name="alterid" size="5" min="1" max="2" value="<?php echo get_option('alterid'); ?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update Options" /></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="alterid" />

    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Use below code where you want alternative results,

```
session_start();

 if($_SESSION['homepagenew'] == '' && $_SESSION['homepageold'] == '')
        {
            if(get_option('alterid') == 1){

                $_SESSION['homepagenew'] = get_option('alterid');
                update_option('alterid', 2 );
            }
            else if(get_option('alterid') == 2){

                 $_SESSION['homepageold'] = get_option('alterid');
                 update_option('alterid', 1 );
            }
        }

    if($_SESSION['homepagenew'] == 1)
        {

              echo do_shortcode('[gravityform shortcode form B]'); // form option 1
              exit; 
        }
    else if($_SESSION['homepageold'] == 2){

            echo do_shortcode('[gravityform shortcode form A]'); // form option 2
             exit; 
        }
```